# how to use findOne and aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
    const detailid = 'jasdfa8d7fa7df9f8fadf'
    UsersModel.findOne({user_detailid: detailid}).aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'user_details',
                localField: 'user_detailid',
                foreignField: 'user_detailid',
                as: 'user_details',
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'user_detailid': detailid
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
    .then((response) => {
        res.json({'code': 200, 'dataUsers': response})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.json({'code': 500, 'error': error.message})
    })
```

i use that function but output with error message "UsersModel.findOne(...).aggregate is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

`findOne` and `aggregate` are two different functions, they can't be chained. If you perform some filtering in the aggregation pipeline, use `$match`.

```
    const detailid = 'jasdfa8d7fa7df9f8fadf'
    UsersModel.aggregate([
        {$match:{user_detailid: detailid}},
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'user_details',
                localField: 'user_detailid',
                foreignField: 'user_detailid',
                as: 'user_details',
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'user_detailid': detailid
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
    .then((response) => {
        res.json({'code': 200, 'dataUsers': response})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.json({'code': 500, 'error': error.message})
    })
```